# PhpMyAdmin and MySQL on MAC

Tags: mysql, macos, phpmyadmin

I have a MAC OS X. I didn't want to use MAMP, so I did install manually.
I have an issue with the connexion between PhpMyadmin and mysql.
I installed Mysql for Mac OS X 10.9 (x86, 64-bit), DMG Archive.

I did set the root password with the command line: mysql_secure_installation
The connexion succeed with Sequel Pro but not with PhpMyAdmin.
I don't understand why I can connect to my DataBase with Sequel Pro but not with PhpMyAdmin. 
Here's the message I got with phpmyadmin: #2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server

I tried to install other version of PhpMyadmin but still the same result.
I even tried to install Mysql with HomeBrew but the result is still the same.
Do I have to config PhpMyAdmin. It's weird because I did install with the same config in another MAC Book Pro and it worked perfectly.

What can be the problem?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Firewall, different default port...

Comment: No there is no firewall, and the default port is the same